# iOS: Most suitable control for selecting from two options

Tags: ios, uiswitch, uicontrol

I am developing an iOS app in which I need a UIControl that allows the user to select between 2 options and 2 options only.

For example, assume I am displaying a form in my app in which the user fills up his personal information like Name, gender, hobbies etc. Here, gender is a possible field for which there are only 2 options (other options are possible, but let's say we don't want it in our app).

I thought it will be nice to use a customized version of the UISwitch for such a case.

But then, I am beginning to think that the UISwitch is applicable only in the context where something is enabled or disabled. Can it also be used in the context where user selects one of 2 choices? Does this go against Apple's design guidelines? If yes, then what other UIControl could I use for this? (I want to use something other than a plain dropdown)

Answer (score 5):

`UISegmentedControl` is your choice.

You can feel free to use other controls (with customized look & feel) in your app, as long as it does not confuse users.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a UISegmentedControl, which has the behavior you require.